# One interface, many listeners

Tags: java, android, events, interface, listener

I have an interface as follow:

```
public interface OnLoadDrawableListener {
    public abstract void onGetDrawable();
}
```

and I have a class named "Content" that implements that:

```
private OnLoadDrawableListener dListener = null;

public void setOnLoadDrawableListener(OnLoadDrawableListener nListener) {
    dListener = nListener;
}
```

then, I want that the follow content:

```
content.setOnLoadDrawableListener(new OnLoadDrawableListener() {

            public void onGetDrawable() {
                imageResultItem.setImageDrawable(content.getImageDrawable()) ;
            }
        });
```

can be implemented in many classes or objects. I had implemented that but the listener only works in the last implementation

Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just change it to:

```
private List<OnLoadDrawableListener> dListeners = new ArrayList<OnLoadDrawableListener>();

public void addOnLoadDrawableListener(OnLoadDrawableListener nListener) {
    dListeners.add(nListener);
}
```

and then iterate through the list when you want to notify your listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array of listeners. As long as you create a new listener an attach it to a different object, it should work properly.

The problem here is that you probably have just one instance of the object "Content". Each instance of "Content" will have its own listener as you set in your code.
Why would you need more than one listener of the same type in the same object?

Comment: The problem is when you need more than one observer. You can have all sorts of listeners attached to different objects, but unless you do it Keppil's way, you can only have one listener for that class.

Comment: Then the implementation is not right. If the observers cover different events they should be of a different type and be registered as well along with the object.
If the observers are the same, they wil be called every time that events happen. There's no need for an array of same type of observers.

Comment: Let's say you have a stock tracker, and a value, say 1000 dollars in your data model somewhere. Then say you have multiple TextViews -- one in one Fragment, one in another, one presents it as "$1,000", the other presents it as "One thousand dollars". Both TextViews should be observing this underlying value so that they are notified when the value changes. I think you may have it in reverse in your head, because having a list of listeners is standard practice.

Comment: Aha, that way seems much clearer. Thanks for your standpoint.

Comment: No problem. :) I'm terrible at coming up with examples, though, haha.

Comment: That example was a very proper one in the times we leave.